# How can I get my React App to display on localhost:3000 using the code provided by the professor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

After a lot of trial and error, the app was displaying.  The app stopped displaying and showing an error page after  I followed the instructions in the part 1 video of the React Components, and deleted from the code of the file App.js from the `render() { -> return () ->  <div className="App">;` well I deleted like the professor said from the `<div> <className="App".>`

What was left after `render() { -> return () ->` was `<div>`.  As far as I know the rest of the code in the file App.js was the same as what  the professor instructed in the video and the printed instructions.

This is my file App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import './App.css';
import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

class App extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       dishes: DISHES
     };
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Navbar color dark color="primary">
            <div className="container">
              <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
           </div>
         </Navbar>
         <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
       </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

At first I tried following the error that the page was showing and attempted on several occasions to fix in the code what the localhost:3000 was telling me to fix, but still there were always more errors to fix.  Now today it is not displaying at all and won't connect to the React App.

I also follow several instructions from several websites that suggested how to fix the problem including creating in the project folder a folder named .env and a subfolder named PORT=4000.  As per the instructions on Github, I then opened a Powershell window and typed yarn start but it did not work I got errors on the command window and I also continued to get a webpage that does not display the App.

Comment: What error you are getting , can you paste the error too ?

Comment: Your `component`-related code looks good, unless it's an issue with components that you're importing (`NavBar`, `NavbarBrand`, and/or `Menu`). If you're having issues starting your application perhaps you did not install dependencies with `npm install`? By the way, `.env` is not a folder but a file that holds your `environment variables`, so not sure what you have going on there.

Comment: Can we get the error.